# More then one Post Type Failing with Pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have been searching for two days now and have not found a solution. Hopefully someone out there can help. Whenever I add an additional post_type the pagination will not work beyond the first page.

Example:
mywebsite.com/myreport/       works fine and 10 content are displayed

mywebsite.com/myreport/page2/ leads to a 404 error.

**Code Inside archive-myreport.php**

```
<?php   
$paged = 1;
if(get_query_var('paged')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif(get_query_var('page')) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
}

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query=null;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array ( 'annual-reports', 'current-reports'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>
<a target="blank" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">My Report</a>
<?php
endwhile;

previous_posts_link('Previous 10'); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php next_posts_link('Next 10');

//clear again
$wp_query = null;
//reset
$wp_query = $temp;
?>
```

**Tried Alternative via pre_get_posts:**

I tried adding to functions.php, after doing so, the page would redirect to index.php:

```
function wpa_post_types( $query) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'myreport' )) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'annual-reports', 'current-reports' ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_post_types' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WP_query` try using `query_posts` and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I tried changing the line

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
to
$wp_query = new query_posts( $args );

and the archive page redirects me to index.php file....